# What does # after a column name mean in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have to make table `Address` in SQL Server.

I have attributes `AddressId`, `Street#`, etc.

In Oracle, sign `#` after attribute means primary key, but I have attribute `AddressID` as primary key.

So, any help?

Comment: "*In Oracle, sign # after attribute means primary key*" - that is **completely** wrong. it's just a character that means "number". The only way to define a primary key in Oracle is to create the appropriate constraint

Comment: The answer is correct. Also don’t use special characters in object names.

Answer (score 6):

It means nothing in SQL Server, it's simply part of the columns name. In some dialects a hash/pound (`#`) character means number, so perhaps it is an abbreviation for the name "Street number"? Otherwise no, it's just a suffix with no meaning in SQL Server itself.